# Cutting an Stl mesh for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]I'm a little new to blender so I need help.

I need to cut this mesh/solid stl file for 3d printing, but I don't know how to do it in blender. How would I go about cutting up a mesh into separate solid meshes? I've tried using the bisect tool and I was able to figure out how to cut a slice I wanted in the mesh, but I can't figure out how to make them two separate solid objects. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add screenshots/a .blend file?

Comment: Autodesk Meshmixer is made for prepping 3d prints http://www.meshmixer.com/  It's got a tool called 'cut' with an option 'slice' where both segments can be left over.

Comment: storm trooper dab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

- Select the part you want to separate and press <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate > Selection*
- Or press <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate > By Loose Parts* parts to break whole the object into all independent parts

You can quickly select all linked geometry inside the same object by selecting Faces/Edges/Vertex and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or by hovering the cursor over some peace of geometry and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!! Very helpful!! Although when I do this there's a gaping hole in both meshes where I cut. How would I fill this hole i.e. make both separations complete solids?

Comment: If you Alt select a vertex it should select the whole loop of the 'gapping hole' - once selected you can key Alt + F to fill the selection. You might also want to try K + Z to slice through the whole object instead of Bisect as it can be more predictable.

Comment: As Patdog suggested you can use the operator *Loop Select* to select the whole hole, then just press F to fill it, if you don't mind the NGons

Comment: Okay. I also have one more question. Now that I've cut my model up into pieces for printing, I need to figure out how to position the parts so the flat, cut sides are parallel with the ground. How would I go about doing this? I could just eyeball it using the rotate tool, but it most likely wouldn't be perfectly flat. Is there a way I could perhaps snap/magnetize the cut side of the piece to the top of a block (making it parallel to the ground) and then delete the block?

Comment: Yes, there is. Blender is not very suited for this type of "precision" CAD-like work though, so it is a bit of an involved process requiring a few different steps. You should probably post a new question for it, I'll be happy to address it if I catch it in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is software like 123D Make from Autodesk.  It is freeware designed specifically for slicing STL models into layers:

http://www.123dapp.com/make

AFAIK, it also has options for exporting to 3D printers.

Comment: I do have that software actually, but 123d doesn't have as many design functions as blender. You can import models, but you can only edit them if they were designed in 123D, which my model wasn't.